# How to set reference of one JSON object to another in JSON file

Tags: json

Is there any way to set reference of one JSON object to another?

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: NO

JSON is a very simple data representation format. It contains no support for references within the overall object. May be you could hack up a little, but it will still be up to the program parsing it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can do things like this, but don't know whether is that what you are looking for:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
Persona = {
        "numberOfLegs" : 2
};

Cesar = {
        "basics" : Persona,
    "name" : "Julio Cayo Cesar"
}

document.write( "<br>" + Cesar.name );
document.write( "<br>" + Cesar.basics.numberOfLegs );
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

If you are looking for inheritance, then the answer is definitely not. The only way to do something similar is to use `$.extend( dest, org )` with jQuery.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Nope, by "JSON file" I would assume there's one (huge) JSON object, in which one value "refers" to another within that same object.